# signcode: question about hash of the signing certificate and hash of the timestamp server

Tags: certificate, code-signing, sign, signtool

I'm a bit cunfused about the difference between the algorithm of the signing certificate and algorithm of the timestamp server.

An example. I have signed a `*.exe` file with SHA256:

```
signtool sign /f mycertificate.pfx /p mypassword /td SHA256 /fd SHA256 file.exe
```

and timstamp server that uses sha256 certificate:

```
signtool timestamp /tr http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp file.exe
```

for Window 10 is good (no error), but for Windows 7 the timestamp is wrong.

I have also tried to timestamp the file with another server that uses SHA1 certificate:

```
signtool timestamp /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com file.exe
```

the timestamp now is good for both os

Why windows 7 doesn't accept sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com timestamp?

What is the pros and cons to use different tipe of timestamp server?

**SIDE NOTE**

Google chrome has the same issue on windows seven

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Why windows 7 doesn't accept sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com timestamp?

You need to check if [KB3033929](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3033929/microsoft-security-advisory-availability-of-sha-2-code-signing-support) has installed on Windows7.
Windows7 won't validate SHA256-only signatures without KB3033929.